# Dynamic Server-Side Rendering with Svelte. How to hydrate it on a client?

Tags: server-side-rendering, svelte, hydration

Assume we have a web page with the HTML `lang` attribute set dynamically based on the `Accept-language` header of the request. The body of the page is also language-specific. What I came up with:

```js
require('svelte/register')

// Render the body
const Body = require('./Body.svelte').default
const body = Body.render({ language })

// Render the entire page
const Page = require('./Page.svelte').default
const page = Page.render(Object.assign(body, { language })

// Send page.html to the client
```

Where `Page.svelte` is:

```js
<script>
  export let html
  export let language
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{ language }">
<body>
  { @html html }
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine. But now I'd like to have the page interact. I use the `Body.svelte` in the App and set `hydrate` option:

```js
const app = new App({
  target: document.body,
  hydrate: true
})
```

Without this option set the content is rendered twice. With the option set we have an error in the browser:

```
Uncaught Error: options.hydrate only works if the component was compiled with the `hydratable: true` option
```

We can pass options to the compiler, according to the [documentation](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_register):

```js
require('svelte/register')({ hydratable: true })
```

It says:

> `hydratable: true` adds a marker to each element in the <head> so that the component knows which elements it's responsible for removing during hydration

But I observe no markers. It has no effect on client-side rendering, and the error remains.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have a full example? Many things could be happening but it's hard to know without seeing the full project. FYI here's a full SSR+hydration project https://github.com/PierBover/svelte-ssr-webpack-example

Comment: @Pier I ended up not using hydration at all as it has performance issues: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4975